# How do I create push queue tasks for multiple queues

Tags: google-app-engine

I have defined two Google App Engine push queues called "default" and "fast".  How do I create a task in the "fast" queue?

Here is the queue.yaml:
queue:

```
- name: default
  rate: 20/s
  bucket_size: 10

- name: fast
  rate: 50/s
  bucket_size: 10
```

I have tried multiple things such as modifying the url parameter, but everything lands in the default queue.

Does anybody have code that shows how to send tasks to multiple queues within the same module?

Answer (score 0):

taskque takes an argument called queue_name.

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

task = taskqueue.add(
            url='/your_task_handler_url',
            params={'param1': 'paramval'}, queue_name='fast')
```